# How to examine objects of an ArrayList (java)

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, interface, instanceof

I have an abstract class Rental...I have two more subclasses,SuiteRental and SimpleRoomRental that inherits Rental class.   I have an ArraList in a third class Hotel (not connected with the others) that contains both objects SimpleRoomRental and SuiteRental.

So,I want to examine each object (propably with instance_of) but i can't create a Rental object (cause its abstract class).What type should I declare my 'k' object?!?

any ideas?

```
public void calculateTotalRentalFees (){

      double price=0; 

      for (int i=0; i<rentals.size(); i++){

          if (k instanceof SimpleRoomRental){
            SimpleRoomRental y= new SimpleRoomRental();
            price=price + y.calculateCost();

          }else if(k instanceof SuiteRental){
              SuiteRental z=new SuiteRental();
              price=price + z.calculateCost();

          }

      }
  }
```

Also I have an interface that contains calculateCost() method.

```
public interface Cost {

public interface Costs {
     double calculateCost();             
}
```

}

thank you for your time

Comment: Just because you can't use `new` to create an instance of Rental doesn't mean that you can't have a variable of type Rental. Note that the instanceof checks are useless. Just add a calculateCost() abstract method in Rental. You're completely missing the point of inheritance and polymorphism.

Comment: Declare it as whichever class the `ArrayList` is declared as.

Comment: Well what's the type of `rentals`? Note that you almost certainly want to cast `k` to `SimpleRoomRental` or `SuiteRental` rather than creating new instances... and I suspect you'd be better off with an enhanced `for` loop. But do you even need to cast them? Doesn't `Rental` have a `calculateCost()` method? It sounds like it should have, and if `rentals` is an `ArrayList<Rental>`, that's all you need.

Comment: Fundamentally though, we need a [mcve] to provide a lot more information...

Comment: @JonSkeet the type of 'rentals' is 'ArrayList<Rental>'.Rental doents have a 'calculateCost()'  cause I have to use somehow the inteface!

Comment: Well what sort of rental doesn't have a cost? Maybe `Rental` should implement `Cost`. You still haven't provided all the relevant information *in the question*.

Comment: The programming technique is called "Polymorphism". There is a lot of material on the web for the interested. It is definitely not possible to instantiate an abstract class, but you can instantiate a concrete class as any parent class. It is for example possible to write `CharSequence cs = new String("hi")`. I am not entirely sure what the problem is though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using interfaces you are also able to handle them both, that's the benefit of using polymorphism, they can even have different implementations for that method!

```
RoomRental rental = new SimpleRoomRental(); 
// You can use too: new SuiteRental();
price = price + rental.calculateCost();
```

Comment: but how am I supposed to examine if the current object of the ArrayList is
SimpleRoomRental or SuiteRental ? :/

Comment: You should be using arrayList.get(i) then.. since in your example you are using `new`.